# Not all input fields zoom in

Tags: ios, css

On iOS,
There is a inconsistently of feature in the browser where I have a review page where users are able to insert their reviews. The css for the input are of 14px. For iOS devices, user will be 'zoomed in' because the font size is smaller than of 16px. Weirdly, of a login page and checkout page, the fields are of 14px as well but it doesnt 'zoomed in'. Im trying to find the pattern here before just increase the font size to just 16px. Do anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using EM instead of PX, An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the font-size of the document is 12px, 1em is equal to 12px. **Ems are scalable in nature.**

Read below article:
https://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: i believe the px denomination can still be used in this sense. so regardless, if a certain EM is being used, we would still know the value in PX. Thus trying to find out why the zoomed in behaviour is as such